# Incorrect Dutch hypenation of `bijlage` with `babel`

Tags: babel, hyphenation, polyglossia

I was checking the hyphenation of `Bijlage` (Dutch) in (Lua)LaTeX using babel or polyglossia (using `\showhyphens`), and noticed that babel incorrectly hyphenates it as `Bij-lage`, while polyglossia gives the correct `Bij-la-ge`.

I'm not sure where to file an issue. I thought babel and polyglossia used the same hyphenation patterns. **What would be the best place to file an issue?**

PS: Maybe unrelated, but both babel and polyglossia incorrectly inhibit the first hyphenation point when the `ij` in bijlage is replaced by `\ij` (or the equivalent unicode symbol `ĳ`).

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Bijlage \showhyphens{Bijlage} % Bij-lage (incorrect)

    Bĳlage \showhyphens{Bĳlage} % Bĳlage (incorrect)
\end{document}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{dutch}

\begin{document}
    Bijlage \showhyphens{Bijlage} % Bij-la-ge (correct!)

    Bĳlage \showhyphens{Bĳlage} % Bĳla-ge (incorrect)
\end{document}
```

PS 2: I know how to use `\babelhyphenation`, but I would like to contribute to the hyphenation patterns if possible. I just don't know how/where.

Comment: Good place to ask. :-)

Comment: the babel dutch module sets the right hyphenmin to 3, add `\renewcommand\dutchhyphenmins{22}` to set it to two.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But why does if fail do hyphenate after the unicode symbol or `\ij`? Is it expected, or an error?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! Do you happen to know whether setting it to three was a conscious choice? Because for e.g. German it is 2...

Comment: sorry but how should one know why someone choose 3 over 2 some decades before? You could write the maintainer and ask, but quite probably he won't remember ....

Comment: @gusbrs I have no idea how dutch hyphenation (and orthography) is supposed to work, but it is certainly possible that this is missing in the patterns. You could write the hyphenation list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, sorry. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I found that <https://github.com/hyphenation/tex-hyphen> is the place to report issues about the hyphenation patterns. Curiously though, the hyphenation pattern file `hyph-nl.tex` says in a comment that it should be used with `hyphenmins` 2,2.

Comment: `bij-lage` is not “incorrect”, but rather incomplete. With TeX you're never sure to get “all feasible” hyphenation points. For instance in English hyphenation you get no hyphenation point for “record”, because correctly hyphenating it requires to know whether its a verb or a noun.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. Still quite unfortunate that `Bĳlage` (using the unicode `ĳ` symbol) has no hyphenation points at all, while it has two according to the dictionary. It is not an uncommon word, it's hyphenation is not context/meaning dependent, or any other strange things (we have words in Dutch where hyphenation can inhibit a syllable, e.g. `menuutje` -> `menu-tje`).

Comment: @beehive “a comment that it should be used with hyphenmins 2,2”. Actually what this comment means is the patterns where generated having these values in mind as a lower limit, not that they should be used. The hyphenmin values are in fact a choice of style depending on several factors. I’m not sure about Dutch, but in Spanish 2,3 are the recommended value in general, but 2,2 is better if the lines are short, and 3,3 may be preferable if they are long. Depending on the document `Bij-la-ge` can be ‘wrong’ in the sense two letters at the beginning of the line are not desirable.

Comment: @beehive Please note that the ij is universally encoded as two characters. Hence, the unicode ij digraph should never be used as input character. Fonts containing the ligature can (should) select it with their own substitution tables, in which case the ligature decomposes for purposes of copying and hyphenation into two characters automatically. Thus, hyphenation patterns not including rules for \ij is not a bug.